# Does moving a project to a folder has impact in google cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, project-organization

Does moving a project to a folder has impact ? the project to move is already in Prod.

Below is an example of what I currently have in my Organization, I want to move "my first project" and "test" to the folder Data-platform.

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving a project do not have impact on current resources.

However, for the new resource, created after the migration, some Organisation policy can apply and can impact the previous behavior if that organisation policy was not set (or configure differently).

For instance, or policy that allow a subset of usable image for VM or the public IP restriction on VM. that can cause the incapacity to create new VM for instance.

---

Similarly, all the inherited stuff, like permissions/roles or hierarchical firewall rules will apply